# VERNEMQ auth using SQL Server

Tags: mqtt-vernemq

I am trying to design something to authenticate my VERNEMQ mqtt broker clients using a SQL Server backend. I've read about webhooks and can use it but the deal breaker being that it does not support HTTPS. Was wondering if we can make vernemq directly authenticate from SQL Server, I've seen existing implementations on cockroach DB/Mongo/MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

I think your 2 best options are a) to develop a native Plugin, possibly over ODBC driver, or b) contribute HTTPS WebHooks support to the VerneMQ project.
(as a maintainer of the project, I can say that PR's are always welcome ;)